# Calculating file offset from RVA in .NET Assembly

Tags: clr

I'm trying to calculate the CLI Header file offset using the optional header, I manually checked a sample .NET Assembly and noticed that the optional header gives me the RVA for the CLI Header which is `0x2008` and the file offset of the CLI Header is `0x208`. How can I calculate the file offset from the RVA?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PE file contains a bunch of sections that get mapped to page aligned virtual addresses using the section table (just after the optional header).

So to read the CLI Header, you can either:

- use something like [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [LoadLibraryEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to map it into memory and then just add the RVA to the returned module base address,
- or you can read the section table and use it to map the RVA to a file position.

```
/* pseudo code */
int GetFilePosition(int rva)
{
    foreach (var section in Sections)
    {
        var pos = rva - section.VirtualAddress;

        if (pos >= 0 && pos < section.VirtualSize)
        {
            return pos + section.PointerToRawData;
        }
    }

    Explode();
}
```

The Section table is described in [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) Partition II Section 25.3

Comment: Can I assume that all the CLI data including header/metadata/metadata tables/heaps located in the .text section and calculate the difference between the rva and the file offset once, and use this value when referring to the CLI data?

Comment: Ultimately, that's entirely up to the compiler. There is no requirement for it to be in any particular section. In practice, I have only ever seen C# and ILASM put it in `.text` while C++/CLI seems to prefer `.rdata`.