# How to modify byte values in binary file for corresponding IL instructions?

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

So I'd like to modify the content of certain methods in a .NET assembly, and the best thing I could find seemed to be Mono.Cecil. However, I also need to be able to modify the corresponding bytes for each IL instruction directly. Would this be possible with Mono.Cecil? Or can I in some way get the address of the corresponding bytes for each instruction, in the .exe file? 
If not, is there any alternative that I can use for this?

Comment: Why can you not modify the assembly with mono Cecil and then write it to disk?

Comment: Because I'd like to do something like XOR'ing the bytes in the method body so it becomes invalid. Then later I'd restore it again.

Comment: I'm not sure if mono Cecil or dnlib actually provides the offset off a method. But loading the assembly as byte array and in it search for `MethodBody.GetILAsByteArray()` should give you the option to find the right offset.

Comment: Good idea. However I just found out that Cecil has a `MethodDefinition.RVA` property which I can use for finding the file offset and then modify the bytes directly.
Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: Keep in mind that you will need to [map the RVA to a file offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35209012/calculating-file-offset-from-rva-in-net-assembly/35221112#35221112) using the PE section table. Also, the resulting location will hold the method header, which could be 1 or 12 bytes before the actual IL (see ECMA-335 Partition II, section 25.4)